# Remove "No products found" from a specific product category in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

How do I delete a message "No products found" from a single category page? I tried various variations of the code below, but it did not work.

```
add_action( 'init','remove_woocommerce_no_products_found' );
function remove_woocommerce_no_products_found() {
    if (is_product_category('name-page')) {
        remove_action('woocommerce_no_products_found', 'action_woocommerce_no_products_found' );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very near… Try the following instead:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_no_products_found','remove_wc_no_products_found', 1 );
function remove_wc_no_products_found() {
    if ( is_product_category('witches') ) {
        remove_action('woocommerce_no_products_found', 'wc_no_products_found' );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works. 
*(Does not add the code in the template herself)*